# Docker container cannot resolve hostnames

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i am creating a docker-compose.yaml file that has to create a pypi local repository and a container with a dev application i am writing. The problem is that, inspite of the fact that i have created custom network and specified hostnames, containers cannot see each other.

More specifically, pypi has to be up and running; during my tests, i ran it manually, and msalembic should use the local pypi repository to load eggs. But i can't see the pypi host.

```
version: '3'
services:
  # Alembic MS
  msalembic:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AlembicMSDockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    hostname: alembicms
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}/msalembic/postgres/psql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${PGUSER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PGPASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: goodboy
      ENVIRONMENT: ${ENVIRONMENT}
    networks:
      - custom_network
    depends_on:
        - pypi
  # Private internal Pypi repository
  pypi:
    build:
        context: pypi
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
          HTACCESS: ${HTACCESS}
    hostname: pypi
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}/pypi/:/srv/pypi:rw"
    ports:
      - "9090:80"
    container_name: pypi
    networks:
      - custom_network
networks:
  custom_network:
```

Contents of the AlembicMSDockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
MAINTAINER Bruno Ripa <XXX>
#RUN pip install -f http://pypi:9090 --trusted-host pypi alembicms
RUN ping pypi
ENTRYPOINT ["alembicms"]
```

Of course i can browse and publish packages in the local pypi repository.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The port mapping you specified is only relevant when the ports of a container are exposed to the host network (e.g. if you want to access them from your host via `http://localhost:9090`).

When linking containers inside a docker network, the services are exposed on the ports defined in the `Dockerfile`. So, according to your port mapping, the `pypi` container exposes port 80, which you should also use when you want to access it from another container in the same docker network.

So, when you run the **built** image of AlembicMSDockerfile, you can access your pypi container on port 80 via the docker network. In your special case, you want to access the pypi container already during build time of the alembic ms image. This is currently not supported within docker-compose as you can read from [the issues here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4665).

As long as this is not released, you could probably run the pypi container on its own and use the `docker build --net=host --add-host=pypi_on_host:<yourhostip> --file=AlembicMSDockerfile` and then modify the RUN command to use `http://pypi_on_host:9090` (where you need the mapped port, as you no longer access it using a docker internal network). Not really elegant, but at least there is no direct reference to your host IP in the Dockerfile then...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i will try asap and give feedback !